# What role did the Higgs boson play in the Big Bang?

Tags: energy, cosmology, universe

1. Scientists say that inflation stopped when a very peculiar energy was mobilized, did Higgs boson play any role in this?
2. What is it's relation to the Big Bang?
3. Some physicists, such as Michio Kaku, say that Higgs boson was the particle that put the bang in the Big Bang, what does it mean?

Comment: see the Wikipedia article on the [Inflaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflaton), which is a general term for a scalar field which drives inflation. The Higgs field is a scalar field and could be the Inflaton (i.e. drive inflation).